# gas furnace transformer grounded

Tags: transformer

### Question: How is a furnace transformer grounded?

I am replacing my York gas furnace's transformer (Mars 503554 40VA 120/24) due to it blowing out after attempting to install an Ecobee 5 smart tstat.  I don't see a ground wire. Is a furnace transformer grounded through some connection off the board? The wiring schematic shows 5 GND - one directly on motor and 4 on chassis. I appreciate hearing back from someone who knows a heck of a lot more than I know!
BTW - my furnace does not have a 3amp fuse, but I plan to piggy back one on the secondary side of the transformer. I also purchased a popper so I don't blow the new transformer.
thanks for your help.

Comment: Usually metal(transformer housing) connected(screwed) to grounded metal(furnace housing) is good enough.  Ground wire only needed for metal insulated(plastic/rubber) from metal contact.

Answer (score 1):

The xformer is grounded by holding screws onto the metal chassis of the gas furnace which is grounded separately.

If for some reason it is not mounted to the metal chassis, it will need grounding.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you Ruskes & @crip659  - it is attached to the chassis . I wanted to be safe before turning on.